# Queue stuck in loop

Tags: c, algorithm, gcc, queue

I implemented queue in C as below. But it stuck in loop.
If I remove `free()` from the `deQueue()` then it work fine.
What is the reason of this behavior.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct item{

    int value;
    struct item* next;
};

struct item *front = NULL, *rear = NULL;

bool isEmpty(){

    return (front == NULL);
}

bool isFull(){

    return false;
}

bool enQueue( int value ) {

    struct item *temp = (struct item*) malloc( sizeof( struct item ) );
    if( temp == NULL ) {

        return false;
    }

    temp->value = value;
    temp->next = NULL;

    if( front == NULL ) {

        printf("Front is NULL\n");

        front = temp;
    }

    if( rear == NULL ) {

        printf("Rear is NULL\n");
        rear = temp;
    } else {

        printf("Rear Value %d \n", rear->value );

        rear->next = temp;
        rear = rear->next;

        printf("Rear Value %d \n", rear->value );
    }

    return true;
}

struct item* deQueue() {

    struct item *temp = front;
    front = front->next;

    return temp;
}

struct item* getFront(){

    return front;
}

struct item* getRear(){

    return rear;
}

void display(){

    struct item* temp = front;
    printf("\n[ ");
    while( temp ){

        printf("%d, ", temp->value);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("]\n");
}

int main(){

    enQueue(1);
    display();
    free(deQueue());
    display();
    enQueue(2);
    display();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik has pointed out the culprit.  FYI, you can see the execution of your code here: https://segfault.stensal.com/a/oUHkQSia1a57g0ww,  You can fix it and test it again.

Answer (score 4):

`deQueue` updates `front` but not `rear`. The latter is left a dangling pointer, after the item is destroyed from under it.

Comment: But why its creating it circular everytime like rear->next = rear

Comment: @Dau I'm not sure what you mean, but adding `if (rear == temp) { rear == NULL; }` to `deQueue` should fix the problem.

Comment: @Dau The next `enQueue();` after `free(deQueue());` is probably allocating the same block of memory that was just freed and that the `rear` variable is still pointing to (because you didn't set it to `NULL`). So `rear->next = temp;` ends up pointing to itself.

Comment: Thanks @IanAbbott actually I have already fixed the issue, but was not able to understand this behaviour. Thanks for your comment and explanation.